# Need 12 column form, split into two columns of 6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap 4 alpha 6

I have a contact form that is supposed to look like this:

[image]

Using the following code, I am able to get two columns of 6, but the fields are all wrong.  This is the code for the section:

```
<section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                <hr width="30%">
                <p>Need to get in touch? Fill in the form below for more information</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <form class="form-inline col-md-12" role="form">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="email...">
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name...">
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="subject...">
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="" id="message" rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="message..."></textarea>
                    </fieldset>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is what the form looks like with the above code:

[image]

As you can see, the columns are split correctly, but the fields are not populating the entire width of the columns.  I looked at it in firebug, and it shows the form-inline class having a width: auto.

```
 .form-inline .form-control {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     width: auto;
 }
```

If I shut off width: auto; in firebug, then the controls populate the full width of the six columns.  I can fix this in my own stylesheet by adding a new class and doing this:

```
 .contact-control 
 {
    width: 100% !important;  
 }
```

I am just wondering if there's a better way to do it, using existing classes in bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it must be better to use div with class form-group rather than fieldset.I hope this  may help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h2><b>Contact Us</b></h2>
                    <hr width="30%">
                    <p>Need to get in touch? Fill in the form below for more information</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Subject">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" rows="4" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Subject" ></textarea>
                    </div>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I case if you add form tag to it and it not work. I have very good example here, with any CSS

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <h4 class="heading">Utvärderingsformulär RETTS Nära Pilot - (Tranås VC)</h4>
         <hr>
      </div>
   </div>
   <form id="datainsamlingForm" method="POST" target="no-targer">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">App version number</label>
            <select class="form-control">
               <option>Version 1</option>
               <option>Version 2</option>
               <option>Version 3</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="control-label">Push Message</label>
               <p class="help-block"><small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</small></p>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess1">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Content</label>
            <p class="help-block"><small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</small></p>
            <select class="form-control">
               <option>Offer 1</option>
               <option>Offer 2</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Play sound</label>
            <p class="help-block"><small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</small></p>
            <select class="form-control">
               <option>Sound 1</option>
               <option>Sound 2</option>
               <option>Sound 3</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="control-label">Publish date/time</label>
               <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span> 
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="control-label">Expire date/time</label>
               <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span> 
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2>
               <a type="button" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg">Publish</a>
            </h2>
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
   </form>
</div>
```